# Where to get algorithm on vp8 encoding algorithm ?(at least base profile)

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing, webm, vp8

I tried search on official Google WebM site but have found nohing... What I need is simple - step by step algorithm of encoding process - from images to encoded video. Where to get such detailed algorithm (not digging into source)?

Answer (score 2):

The official published algorithm, in the spec, is basically just source code snippets. I'd advise you actually look at the code.

Comment: could you provide more links?